# AddThis twttrhubframe blocking clicks on ie7

Tags: iframe, twitter, internet-explorer-7, click, addthis

I'm using Add-This to add "Tweet" and "Like" buttons to my page.

The script I am including is the one below:

http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js

It adds the slightly famous #twttrhubframe and #twttrhubframesecure iframes to the top of the page just inside the body tag.

On most browsers these iframes are hidden, far left aligned (left:-9999px) etc and don't cause an issues.

In IE7 when I include the above script I am unable to click on any link or select any text anywhere on my page. This suggests that the twttr iframes are covering my page and blocking my mouse events.

I have the following additional styles applied to no effect:

```
#twttrHubFrame, #twttrHubFrameSecure  { 
    left:-100000px; 
    width:0px; 
    height:0px;
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    z-index:-100;
}
```

If I remove the script (thus stopping the inclusion of the iframes) all clicks work fine.

Has anyone encountered this and solved it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be caused by having position:relative; set on the body.

Comment: Totally...how did I miss that! ;) Thanks.